# Crear varios proxies socks5 en VPS con múltiples IP públicas?

Tags: socket, tcpip

Tengo un VPS Ubuntu con 4 IPs publicas. Quisiera saber cuál es la mejor manera para, instalando algún servidor socks5 como Dante, por ejemplo, poder usar estas 4 IPs públicas como proxies socks5.

Sé que hay manera con Squid para proxies HTTP/S pero necesito socks5, los usaría en firefox, curl, etc.

Quizás haya algún script que facilite el proceso o quizás otra forma y, si es posible asociar subdominios a cada IP para usarlas en otro nuevo VPS por si el que tengo tiene una falla, mejor.

Hasta ahora solo probé este VPS creando túnel SSH local y colocando esos datos en Firefox y la IP pública siempre es la misma, la IP principal, pero igual quisiera hacerlo con un servidor sock5 como Dante, que seria mas fácil que tener que crear túneles SSH cada vez que se necesite usar.

¡Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1):

En el archivo de configuración de Dante, [`socks.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sockd.conf), puedes usar el siguiente parámetro de configuración que permite seleccionar la dirección IP o interfaz que se usará en las conexiones salientes:

> **external**
>
> The address to be used for outgoing connections. The address given may be either a IP address or an interface name. Can be given multiple times for different addresses.

En castellano:

> **external**
>
> La dirección a ser usada por las conexiones salientes. La dirección proporcionada podría ser una dirección IP o el nombre de una interfaz. Puede indicarse múltiples veces para múltiples direcciones.

Puedes indicar varias direcciones IP o interfaces junto con la opción `external.rotation` para que las conexiones salientes roten entre varias interfaces y/o direcciones IP de diferentes maneras.

Puedes ejecutar varias instancias del servidor con una dirección IP configurada en cada una de ellas o bien todas las direcciones IP en una misma instancia dependiendo del uso que desees darle.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias Oscar, entonces si la maquina tiene 4 ips, y hago la configuracion que decis, en firefox iria solamente 1 de las IPs y Dante rotaria entre las 4 us por cada conexion?  TAMBIEN vi esto en github: https://github.com/lozy/danted que creo que serviria.

Comment: Si configuras cuatro servidores Dante, cada uno escuchando en un puerto distinto y con una IP saliente diferente, podrás cambiar en Firefox de IP saliente cambiando el puerto del Dante cuya IP desees usar. También está la opción de usar un único Dante que va rotando las IPs salientes con cada petición atendiendo a una regla definida por `external.rotation`. Una de las reglas es mantener la misma IP cuando visites la misma IP externa, otra cambia la IP en cada conexión nueva, etc.